# When div is added to dom enable it to be droppable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to allow a new div that is added dynamically to a dom to be made droppable ?

I'm trying this :

```
var myDroppable = '<div id="myDroppableDiv" >New droppable</div>';
$("#myDroppables").append(myDroppable );
```

But receive this error :

```
Object has no method 'droppable'
```

Comment: I think that error is coming from somewhere else.  Are you sure you have the right line of code with the error?  It probably has `.droppable(...)`.

Comment: Why do you have one `<div..>` opening tag, but two closing tags?

Comment: @Blazemonger sorry, typo. updated

Comment: Have you included jQuery UI script. `droppable` is part if jQuery UI lib and make sure you have included it.

Comment: since youre adding the div dynamically, you probably need to use a method like on to manage its events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just invoke the `droppable` method as soon as its appended:

```
$(myDroppable).appendTo('#myDroppables').droppable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep; you can do it this way:

```
​var d = $('<div />').droppable();​​​​​
​d.appendTo('body');​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/t4CCn/).

Comment: `.droppable()` retrieves `.offsetWidth/Height` in the constructor so it should be in the dom before you call it. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.droppable.js#L40 Otherwise they will be given `0` as values and I don't know what side effects that might have.